# Windows 8.1 search doesn't search drives other than C:\

Tags: search, windows-8.1

I have a file called `ftb_launcher.exe` saved in `D:\FTB\ftb_launcher.exe`.

My windows drive is `C:\`. I have bing search off.

If I search for `ftb_launcher.exe` nothing comes up. However, if I put it in my `Documents` folder, it comes up.

How do I make it search my entire `D:\` drive?

I want to have it search for all files in `D:\` by the way, not just `ftb_launcher.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search (in Windows) for "Indexing Options".

[image]

Click "Modify" and ensure your drive is selected to be included in the search index.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows only searches `C:\Users\`, but you can add folders/drives to your index, as outlined [here](http://m.blog.laptopmag.com/windows-81-search-index).

Summary:

1. Control Panel
2. Indexing Options
3. Click Modify
4. Add Folders/Drives

Note, if your index is too large, you'll likely notice performance impacts.