# How to index a hard drive on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-search

I want to index my 2 partitions made on my Windows 7 machine for better search performance. I did however, when I was prompted to index, not do so at the time. Any other way to do this?

Note: I would prefer doing it Windows way, not downloading some 3rd party program do so for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 search doesn't search drives other than C:∖](http://superuser.com/questions/682312/windows-8-1-search-doesnt-search-drives-other-than-c)

Comment: While in theory that question is the same as mine, it is still based on Windows 7 which makes it slightly different. But feel free to mark as duplicate if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open up My Computer
- Right click the drive you want to index
- Select Properties
- At the bottom of the General tab (default tab), check the checkbox "Allow files on the drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties"
- Repeat for other drives/partitions you wish to index